# Unable to append params dynamically to the API using angular datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

Trying to load datatable with few records initially and once datatable loaded, trying to click pagination buttons, here trying like if we click on pagination button need to reload the API with latest with updated params and load set of records instead of all records at a time. Developed below code for pagination for huge data,

```
loadTable() {
    this.dtOptions = {
      processing: true,
      destroy: true,
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      columns: [
        { title: '<input type="checkbox" />' },
        { data: 'index' },
        { data: 'firstname' },
        { data: 'lastname' }
      ],
      infoCallback: (oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre) => {
        pageStartNo = iStart;
        pageEndNo = iEnd;
        console.log(pageStartNo, pageEndNo);
        params = new HttpParams()
          .set('param1', '111')
          .set('param2', '222')
          .set('minNumber', pageStartNo)
          .set('maxNumber', pageEndNo);
        console.log('params >>>>>>>>>>>>>' + params.toString());
      }
    };
    this.http
      .get<any[]>(
        'https://angular-datatables-demo-server.herokuapp.com/',
        {
          params
        }
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.persons = response.data;
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      });
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/passing-pagination-params-and-draw-the-table-ew5wgn)

Comment: Have you tried {params: params} ?

Comment: yes, tried... But here..API is not triggering while clicking on Datatable pagination buttons.